# Too many auth dialogs when using ADAL.JS on my portal page with cookie auth to call my WebAPI that uses JWT auth

Tags: ajax, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, adal.js

I have the following setup:

1) WebAPI that accepts JWT Bearer tokens for auth.

2) Portal (WebApp) that puts a nice face on the json output from this WebAPI. It does OpenIdConnect authentication and uses Cookies to persist login information. It is an ASP.NET Core MVC app.

3) The WebAPI and WebApp are on different domains.

4) The WebAPI layer is designed to be called by any 3rd party who can present a valid token - either via App auth (client_credential flow, for eg) OR Delegated User auth (implicit flow, for eg). The WebAPI also does RBAC auth.

At this point, the problem I have is this:

1) **I want to be able to make AJAX calls from the WebApp controller pages (cshtml) to my WebAPI so that the pages are responsive and there are no POSTs.** So I integrated ADAL.JS into the page for that purpose. It works from a functionality pov.

2) **HOWEVER**, this results in **multiple authentication dialogs** (web page popups).

-- 1st auth popup. Upon navigation to the Portal homepage, I get challenged and have to enter my credentials on my company login page (federated AD auth).

-- 2nd auth popup. Then when I invoke anything on the Portal pages that involves ADAL.JS (namely the AJAX calls), it causes another login dialog because ADAL.JS cannot see the login cookie from ADAL.NET layer. This dialog comes up and goes away without any input needed tho (because the cookies from (1) are sent along to the server automatically by the browser). At this point, I have the ID_TOKEN and an ACCESSTOKEN for the PortalApp's client_id show up in the ADAL localStorage area.

-- 3rd auth popup. Then another dialog pops up; it uses a Hello pin login (I assume this is due to 2-factor auth requirement enforced by my tenant). At this point, I see the ACCESS TOKEN for the WebAPIApp's client_id show up in the ADAL LocalStorage area.

And now my AJAX calls start working.

Is there a better way to do this so that I can get the benefits of AJAX and not have to resort to serverside POSTs and have only 1 auth dialog instead of 3?

(I thought of may be switching ALL authentication to be done by ADAL.JS for the entire site, but I like the paradigm of using the [Authorize] flags and RBAC for the Controllers. OR is there a way to make my WebAPI accept **both** JWT and Cookie authentication?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing I have done that is making this slightly better:
1) Changed {"popup"} to False. 

Good news is this prevents BOTH 2nd and 3rd popups; they are gone, and instead the tokens arrive in the SAME WINDOW via the redirect.

the bad news is 1) This leaves the Token in the URL area ("well") of the browser so it looks kinda unpolished. 2) This one is bad - if I arrive at the site via a link DIFFERENT than the redirectUri (which is the site homepage) then I get PUT on the redirectUri site - only happens when the cookies/tokens are missing tho.